# I use PHP & MySQLi. now I need to obtain count values for particular value which is at database?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

How do I count particular values from database and display it?
Now I have different feedback such like Excellent, Very Good, Good etc. It's basically a feedback form which ratings based

```
<?php
$sql_query_very_good = "SELECT *,COUNT(*) AS very_good_count FROM visitors_feedback
WHERE question01_answer LIKE '%Very Good%'
OR question02_answer LIKE '%Very Good%'
OR question03_answer LIKE '%Very Good%'
OR question04_answer LIKE '%Very Good%'
OR question05_answer LIKE '%Very Good%'
OR question06_answer LIKE '%Very Good%'
";

$result_very_good = mysqli_query($db, $sql_query_very_good);

while($view_very_good = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_very_good)):

?>

<td><?php echo $view_very_good['very_good_count']; ?></td>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: what error are you getting from your current code?

Comment: Hi @Twista my output should come 2 or 3 etc but i am getting only 1.

Comment: i am getting feedback from clients and i need to count them based on value such as Excellent,Good,Very Good 

@ https://pasteboard.co/HXABgVZ.png